# Phonegap and requirejs dynamic script loading fails

Tags: javascript, cordova, requirejs

I'm just starting out with phonegap. I have an existing app that's a Java servlet container. I've written a simple crawler that extracts all the relevant JS and CSS and images, etc. So I now have a straight forward HTML app. It uses requirejs.

I'm now trying to get it building with phonegap. However, I've come across the following issue, which might be a bug? Or something I'm doing is wrong.

The following happens:

1. Page loads up fine
2. Click around works fine
3. The app will be changing the URL in the background (using Backbone)
4. Finally, I click a button which trigger requirejs, which in turn tries to load a script.
5. I can see the following error when I'm using Chrome to debug the WebView on my Android vm

> GET file:///js/step.search-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js 
>   step.2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for: search
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>   step.2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js:1
>
> GET file:///js/step.qtip-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js 
>   step.2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for: qtip
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> GET file:///js/step.quick-lexicon-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js 
>   step.2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for:
>   quick_lexicon http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Is this a bug?

Here's my requirejs config

```
requirejs.config({
waitSeconds: 15000,

paths : {
    sidebar: ["js/step.sidebar-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    quick_lexicon : ["js/step.quick-lexicon-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    qtip : ["js/step.qtip-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    view_help_menu: ["js/step.help-menu-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    drag: ["js/step.draggabilly-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    menu_extras: ["js/step.menu_extras-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    html2canvas: ["js/step.html2canvas-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"],
    search: ["js/step.search-STEP_SERVER_VERSION_TOKEN.min"]
}
```

});

I've also noticed the following behaviour:

- If I open up the chrome dev console, and attempt to write a  tag when the page first loads up, the file loads fine
- If after clicking some buttons/menus I do the same, the file fails to load, presumably because the URL in the webview has changed?

In other words, if I run the following snippet after my app has rendered, before interacting with it, it works. After interacting with the app it stops working with the same errors as above.

```
$("head").append('<script src="js/step.2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js" type="script/javascript"></script>')
```

In the head, I've noticed that requirejs is correctly putting relative paths, rather than absolute, to the resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="sidebar" src="./js/step.sidebar-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, the URL given by the dev console by window.location.href is:

Before: file:///android_asset/www/index.html"
After:  file:///?q=version=ESV|strong=G0018&options=HVNUG

So I'm going to post this anyway in case other people find the same issue, but I'm reckoning writing this has helped me understand the root of the problem.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

So, pretty sure that the root cause is: using the history URL seems to have moved the browser's location to somewhere which is no longer relative to android_asset/www/index.html, which in turn will break the loading of any further scripts.

The next question, obviously, is how to fix that - and I will dwell on that.  Perhaps a  tag might come in handy. But better still, fix the URL to ensure it remains relative to index.html. That will be likely be specific to my own use case.